# prophet.perdict(future) ValueError couldn't pass any size of future(df)

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet

I'm predicting on dataframe with 17 rows, but it raise *ValueError: Length of passed values is 17, index implies 1*.
How can I predict any length of future dataframe?

*Runing at python=3.6.8, fbprophet version=0.3*
Then I just predicting on dataframe with 1 row. It works.
I change the growth, n_changepoints, changepoint_range, weekly_seasonality, daily_seasonality. It doesn't work.
if the model fit different data, the length limit is changed.

```py
def first_nonzero_index(serial):
    # drop 0 ahead
    for i in serial.index:
        if serial[i] != 0:
            return i
    return None

def model_data_convert(sale_series, has_cap = False, has_floor = False):
    item_id = sale_series.name
    category_id = items.at[item_id, 'item_category_id']
    start_month = first_nonzero_index(sale_series)
    data = sale_series[start_month:].to_frame('y').reset_index()
    data.columns = ['ds', 'y']
    end_time = pd.Period('2015-10', 'M')
    start_time = pd.Period('2013-01') + start_month
    data['ds'] = pd.period_range(start_time.strftime('%Y%m'), end_time.strftime('%Y%m'), freq='M').to_timestamp(how = 'E')
    if has_cap:
        data['cap'] = catergory_cap.loc[category_id][start_month:].values
    if has_floor:
        data['floor'] = catergory_floor.loc[category_id][start_month:].values
    return data

data = common_items_month_sales_without_seasonal.loc[38]
data = model_data_convert(data, has_cap=True, has_floor=True)
m = fbprophet.Prophet(n_changepoints=5,changepoint_range=0.5)
m.fit(data)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=1, freq='M')
future['cap'] = data['cap']
future['floor'] = data['floor']
future = future.fillna(method='ffill')
forecast = m.predict(future)
```

```
data
                              ds         y  cap  floor
0  2014-07-31 23:59:59.999999999  4.075182   72      0
1  2014-08-31 23:59:59.999999999  1.018694   43      0
2  2014-09-30 23:59:59.999999999  6.059121   35      0
3  2014-10-31 23:59:59.999999999  3.514318  258      0
4  2014-11-30 23:59:59.999999999  9.382967   57      0
5  2014-12-31 23:59:59.999999999  7.302505   99      0
6  2015-01-31 23:59:59.999999999  6.587640   47      0
7  2015-02-28 23:59:59.999999999  3.985545   55      0
8  2015-03-31 23:59:59.999999999  0.999565   78      0
9  2015-04-30 23:59:59.999999999  0.000000   61      0
10 2015-05-31 23:59:59.999999999  4.026230   47      0
11 2015-06-30 23:59:59.999999999  2.715869   38      0
12 2015-07-31 23:59:59.999999999  5.093977   53      0
13 2015-08-31 23:59:59.999999999  7.130856   44      0
14 2015-09-30 23:59:59.999999999  2.423648   37      0
15 2015-10-31 23:59:59.999999999  0.000000   39      0

future
                              ds    cap  floor
0  2014-07-31 23:59:59.999999999   72.0    0.0
1  2014-08-31 23:59:59.999999999   43.0    0.0
2  2014-09-30 23:59:59.999999999   35.0    0.0
3  2014-10-31 23:59:59.999999999  258.0    0.0
4  2014-11-30 23:59:59.999999999   57.0    0.0
5  2014-12-31 23:59:59.999999999   99.0    0.0
6  2015-01-31 23:59:59.999999999   47.0    0.0
7  2015-02-28 23:59:59.999999999   55.0    0.0
8  2015-03-31 23:59:59.999999999   78.0    0.0
9  2015-04-30 23:59:59.999999999   61.0    0.0
10 2015-05-31 23:59:59.999999999   47.0    0.0
11 2015-06-30 23:59:59.999999999   38.0    0.0
12 2015-07-31 23:59:59.999999999   53.0    0.0
13 2015-08-31 23:59:59.999999999   44.0    0.0
14 2015-09-30 23:59:59.999999999   37.0    0.0
15 2015-10-31 23:59:59.999999999   39.0    0.0
16 2015-11-30 23:59:59.999999999   39.0    0.0
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\***\.conda\envs\Data\lib\site-packages\fbprophet\forecaster.py", line 1042, in predict
    intervals = self.predict_uncertainty(df)
  File "C:\Users\***\.conda\envs\Data\lib\site-packages\fbprophet\forecaster.py", line 1244, in predict_uncertainty
    sim_values = self.sample_posterior_predictive(df)
  File "C:\Users\***\.conda\envs\Data\lib\site-packages\fbprophet\forecaster.py", line 1208, in sample_posterior_predictive
    s_m=component_cols['multiplicative_terms'],
  File "C:\Users\***\.conda\envs\Data\lib\site-packages\fbprophet\forecaster.py", line 1276, in sample_model
    Xb_a = np.matmul(seasonal_features.values, beta * s_a) * self.y_scale
  File "C:\Users\***\.conda\envs\Data\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 735, in __array_wrap__
    copy=False).__finalize__(self)
  File "C:\Users\***\.conda\envs\Data\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 249, in __init__
    .format(val=len(data), ind=len(index)))
ValueError: Length of passed values is 17, index implies 1
```

Comment: I try example from offical github.The same problem occurs. I suppose it is not the dataset problem.

Comment: It's AMAZING!!  I reinstall fbprophet 0.4post2 with pip in conda prompt. It's all right. WHY? Could anybody tell me?